# What does "inline" mean in the context of cable testing?

Tags: cable, power-over-ethernet, testing

I hope the title is self explanatory. I was unable to find anything about the term on google however my intuition says that an "inline" tester would intercept some signals going from A to B and then display some information about the signal.

This is how I would visualize an "inline" testing device in my head:

`A --------> [Testing device] --------> B`

So maybe it's the language barrier or maybe I'm getting scammed, but what I have been visualising is not something that is supported by my newly purchased "*Inline PoE Tester*". Before I decide how to proceed I wanted to make sure that I got my terminology right and the word "Inline" doesn't mean something completely different in this context.

Comment: If a certain function of a product is important to you, you should make sure of it before purchasing instead of relying on a single word which you might have misinterpreted.

Comment: That's what the returns are for, as for the product itself, it was bought for a completely different reason and the "inline PoE tester" part was a nice bonus on the device which was simply interpreted differently by me when I was trying it out for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Inline” refers to PoE, not to the position of the tester. So this with this tester you can check cables doing power over Ethernet. You would still place the tester at the ends of the cable.